# Unit for Total_LBAs_Written in SMART data

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

I have 3 machines with disks (actually, SSDs) in RAID1, purposely with different brands in an attempt to make it improbable to loose them both simultaneously due to wear-out. They are functional.

They should have approximately the same number of Total_LBAs_Written on their two disks. But the figure are wildly different, e.g. smartctl reports 2596016156 on a Samsung SSD 850 EVO 2TB, but 1237 on the companion WDC WDS200T2B0A-00SM50:

```
241  Total_LBAs_Written  0x0032  099 099 000  Old_age  Always   -  2596016156
241  Total_LBAs_Written  0x0030  253 253 ---  Old_age  Offline  -        1237
```

My best guess is that the first report is in blocks of 512 bytes, and the second in [Gibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte). That would explain that the ratio is 2<sup>21</sup> (within one unit for the smaller value).

**Is the unit for the Total_LBAs_Written entry standardized somewhere? Is there a systematic way to determine it? If not, what units are practiced?**

Update, Oct 2023 (4 years later): that config is still in use (and fine). Now it reads:

```
241  Total_LBAs_Written  0x0032  099 099 000  Old_age  Always   - 219294945066
241  Total_LBAs_Written  0x0030  253 253 ---  Old_age  Offline  -       104567
```

The ratio between the values for the two drives is 2<sup>21</sup> within 0.001%, or 1 unit of the smaller value.

Comment: There is some confusion depending on the manufacturer... https://www.virten.net/2016/12/ssd-total-bytes-written-calculator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your guess is right. I have a HooDisk SSD 128G, and made the following test:

1. read atribute: 289
2. write 1G of data
3. read atribute: 290
4. write 1G of data
5. read atribute: 291

comands:

```
$ smartctl -a /dev/sda |awk '/Total_LBAs_Written/ {print $10}'
289
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/testimage bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 3.54747 s, 303 MB/s
$ smartctl -a /dev/sda |awk '/Total_LBAs_Written/ {print $10}'
290
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/testimage bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 3.42046 s, 314 MB/s
$ smartctl -a /dev/sda |awk '/Total_LBAs_Written/ {print $10}'
291
$
```

based on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes
It didn't say about the unit of this attribute, so I guess its not well standarized, you'd better to specifictly test the device to determine its meanings.

Answer (score 1):

`241  Total_LBAs_Written` is in sector size.

`smartctl /dev/sda --all |grep "Sector Size"` usually gives 512 bytes.
(with /dev/sda your drive).

`241  Total_LBAs_Written  0x0032  099 099 000  Old_age  Always   -  2596016156`
if your sector size is 512, it would give a TBW of 1.33 TB.

[How to- Convert SMART attribute 241-Total_LBAs_Written to TBW MB-GB-TB-PB < Blog-D without Nonsense](https://dannyda.com/2020/09/06/how-to-convert-smart-attribute-241-total_lbas_written-to-mb-gb-tb-pb/)

> LBA (Logical block addressing)

Though the fact that at least certain WD drives report Total_LBAs_Written in GB has been reported to their forums without a reply:
[How to read Total bytes written on 1TB SSD](https://community.wd.com/t/how-to-read-total-bytes-written-on-1tb-ssd/236913)

> 0x01 0x018 6 255445147 — Logical Sectors Written
> which is in number of sectors (look at the sector size at the top of the > smartctl)
>
> Now this is the same as 121GB (for 512 bytes per sector )
> Surprisingly (coincidence?) I see the same value in the LBA_Written
> 241 Total_LBAs_Written ----CK 253 253 — - 121
> This value is supposed to be in 512 byte sector sizes but unfortunately this > reflects GB written (non standard compliance ? IMHO)